# Отфильтровать объект JS

Tags: javascript, filter

Есть объект с вложениями, нужно отфильтровать его ветки по нужному значению в листе.

Дано:

```
let data = '[{"caption":"Настройки","commands":[{"caption":"Основные","commands":[{"caption":"Цены"},{"caption":"Типы цен"},{"caption":"Первичные документы"},{"caption":"Настройка отображения ТМЦ в первичных документах"},{"caption":"Настройка первичных документов"}]},{"caption":"Общие настройки","commands":[{"caption":"Глобальные настройки"},{"caption":"Типы процессов"},{"caption":"Тип процесса (функция)"},{"caption":"Нумераторы"},{"caption":"Тип нумератора"},{"caption":"Нумератор"},{"caption":"Календарь"},{"caption":"Тип календаря"},{"caption":"Рабочий календарь"},{"caption":"Сервисы"},{"caption":"Заполнение пустых кодов"},{"caption":"Заполнить RTClass"}]}]}]';
```

Ожидается

```
let dataRES = '[{"caption":"Настройки","commands":[{"caption":"Основные","commands":[{"caption":"Первичные документы"}]}]}]';
```

То, что набросал, но почему-то не получается

```js
let data = '[{"caption":"Настройки","commands":[{"caption":"Основные","commands":[{"caption":"Цены"},{"caption":"Типы цен"},{"caption":"Первичные документы"},{"caption":"Настройка отображения ТМЦ в первичных документах"},{"caption":"Настройка первичных документов"}]},{"caption":"Общие настройки","commands":[{"caption":"Глобальные настройки"},{"caption":"Типы процессов"},{"caption":"Тип процесса (функция)"},{"caption":"Нумераторы"},{"caption":"Тип нумератора"},{"caption":"Нумератор"},{"caption":"Календарь"},{"caption":"Тип календаря"},{"caption":"Рабочий календарь"},{"caption":"Сервисы"},{"caption":"Заполнение пустых кодов"},{"caption":"Заполнить RTClass"}]}]}]';

function f(data, searchValue) {
  return data.filter((item) => {
    if (item.commands) {
      let res = f(item.commands, searchValue);
      if (res.length > 0) {
        return res
      }
    } else {
      if (item.caption.toLowerCase() === searchValue.toLowerCase()) {
        return item.caption;
      }
    }
  })
}

let dd = JSON.parse(data);
console.log('dd', dd);
let newArr = f(dd, 'Первичные документы');
console.log('>>>newArr', newArr);
```

Comment: `filter` Не меняет коллекцию, он только фильтрует ее, не выводя элементы не подходящие по условию

Comment: Метод «arr.filter(callback[, thisArg])» используется для фильтрации массива через функцию.

Он создаёт новый массив, в который войдут только те элементы arr, для которых вызов callback(item, i, arr) возвратит true.

Опирался на это. Сделал плохим кодом, через map.

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что код через map плох?

Comment: _Метод «arr.filter(callback[, thisArg])» используется для фильтрации массива через функцию._ - именно, **для фильтрации**, ты фильтруешь массив с одним элементом, у тебя этот элемент подходит под условие - следовательно он остается в результирующем массиве. Все именно так как и описано.

Comment: т.к. получилось на мой взгляд - не очень красиво (с undefined элементами и пустыми объектами). После map пришлось еще раз пробежаться по массиву forEach и вот уже тогда, я получил все, что хотел.
Думал можно получить все намного проще и короче(чем 2 прогона)
В конце сделал массив из веток и листа
['1ветка', '2ветка', 'нужный лист']